# How to implement the event onkeyup in JQuery witout using JQuery mobile?

Tags: android, jquery, html, mobile

I have a mobile app and I can't use JQuery Mobile at the moment, **only JQuery**.
I found out that in Android mobile the "onkeyup" event is not working at all, only if the user type "back" the event fires.

I have one "input" field (HTML5) and need to attach the onkeyup event to it. What to do? I tried to replace the val(), adding the val somhting like "#" and remove it quickly. It doesn't helped.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#MyElement").keyup(Function(e) {
$("#MyElement").val("MyValue");
});
});
```

the e param should tell you what key was pressed with the properties keycode and which.
hope this lends you to the right direction.